# error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++, quicksort

I have a quicksort that I wrote here:

```
void swap(int& a, int& b);
int mid(int lo, int hi);

// My quicksort implementation
void sort(int vec[], int lo, int hi)
{
        int mid;
        if (hi > lo) {
                int i = lo + 1;
                int j = hi;
                int p = mid(lo, hi);
                swap(vec[lo], vec[p]);
                mid = vec[lo];
                while (i < j) {
                        if (vec[i] <= mid) {
                                i++;
                        } else {
                                while (i < --j && vec[j] >= mid);
                                swap(vec[i], vec[j]);
                        }
                }
                i++;
                swap(vec[lo], vec[i]);
                sort(vec, lo, i);
                sort(vec, j, hi);
        }
}

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
}

int mid(int lo, int hi)
{
        return lo + ((hi - lo) / 2);
}
```

I tried compiling to an object file with `g++ -g -c array.cpp -o array.o`
I get this error:

```
array.cpp:24:14: error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function
    pointer
            int p = mid(lo, hi);
                    ~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Everything looks correct. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: You declared `int mid;` but call `mid(lo, hi)`...

Comment: In my case I hadn't put semicolon before the line and I was getting the same error. It fixed after I put the semicolon to the previous statement (one line before).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your local variable `mid` is declared in the scope that is closer to the point of use, so it "shadows" the `mid()` function; the compiler thinks that you are trying to "call" an integer, which is invalid. Rename the local variable to fix this problem:

```
int midpoint;
if (hi > lo) {
    int i = lo + 1;
    int j = hi;
    int p = mid(lo, hi);
    swap(vec[lo], vec[p]);
    midpoint = vec[lo];
    ...
}
```

Note: you could also use `::mid(lo, hi)` instead of renaming the variable, but that would confuse the readers of your program.

Comment: +1. Of course, the alternative to renaming would be to use `::mid` to refer to the function.

Comment: Thanks! this helped. I had originally had the variable called pivot and the function pivot() and when I did a global search-and-replace to try and fix the problem I forgot to notice that the variable also changed too.

Comment: @Angew Thanks for an excellent point! I edited the answer to mention this.

Comment: @Pocketkid2 You are welcome! If the answer works for you, consider accepting it to let other site visitors know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, and to earn a couple of reputation points for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
int mid(int lo, int hi);      // here you declared mid as function and defined
                              // it later
// My quicksort implementation
void sort(int vec[], int lo, int hi)

{
int mid;                      // but here you declared mid as local variable
if (hi > lo) {                // it will shadow int mid(int lo, int hi);
        int i = lo + 1;
        int j = hi;
        int p = mid(lo, hi);  // so this is error, mid is integer not a function
```

you can change the name of variable in the algorithm or use scope resolution operator `::mid(lo, hi)` to access `mid` function previously defined in global scope